# Python regexp groups: how do I get all groups?

Tags: python, regex

I am puzzled by this:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r"(?P<all>-(?P<one>\w+))*","-ab-cde-fghi-jkl-mn").groups()
('-mn', 'mn')
>>> re.match(r"(?P<all>-(?P<one>\w+)*)","-ab-cde-fghi-jkl-mn").groups()
('-ab', 'ab')
```

How do I get the list of all terms, ideally like

```
["ab","cde","fghi","jkl","mn"]
```

but

```
"-ab-cde-fghi-jkl-mn"
```

is fine too.

(Please note that I am fully aware of `str.split("-")`. This is a question about `re` - *how to match the whole set*)

Comment: Docs for `match` say: "If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding match object." So only one match is expected, with two groups.

Comment: If you use PyPi regex module, you can access all the groups via `.captures`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

Example:

```
s = "-ab-cde-fghi-jkl-mn"
re.findall(r'[a-z]+', s)
```

Output:

```
['ab', 'cde', 'fghi', 'jkl', 'mn']
```

Answer (score 3):

It works like you want by default in .NET.

Python does not support this though. The closest behavior you could get in Python, would be to repeat the match on the captured substring:

```
>>> match = re.match(r"(?P<all>(?:-(?P<one>\w+))*)","-ab-cde-fghi-jkl-mn")
>>> re.findall(r"-(?P<one>\w+)", match.group("all"))
['ab', 'cde', 'fghi', 'jkl', 'mn']
```

It could get complicated if the inner pattern is not extremely simple.